# How to set minimum value to Radar Chart in chart js

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to create a radar chart in chart js but the issue is chart is starting from 1 and ending at 12 because the min value is 1 and max value is 12, what I want is  to set the default valueof 0 and 15.

```
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "radar",
        data: {
            labels: stockSymbols,
            datasets: [{
                label: "PSX RADAR CHART",
                data: [1,2,3,4,5,8,10,12],
                borderColor: "green",
                borderWidth: 1,
                yAxisID: "y",
            }, ],
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 12,
                    display: true,
                },
            },
        },
    });
```

[this is my radar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8p6m.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radar chart is using the radial scale by default. So changing y to r will solve your issue:

```js
options: {
    scales: {
        r: {
            min: 0,
            max: 15,
        },
    },
},
```